# libspatialite.so spatialite load extension using java

Tags: linux, spatialite

I followed [this link](http://timogrossenbacher.ch/2013/02/how-to-install-spatialite-and-spatialite-gui-on-ubuntu-12-04/) to install Spatialite.

How do I use the spatialite installation in my Java code? Which extension do I load for spatialite function

`addGeometry()` (Linux / Ubuntu)

In windows I tried this and it worked but not for Ubuntu:

```
stmt.execute("SELECT load_extension('libspatialite.dll')");
stmt.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData()");
```

Comment: need to work on ubuntu with java so any method that works with linux and java for spatialite is welcome...pl pl

Comment: Have you tried changing "libspatialite.dll" to "libspatialite.so" ?

Answer (score 1):

You should change extension to .so (this is the Linux .dll)